# how to add parameter in php callback

Tags: php, callback

I struggle to understand how I can add a second parameter ($id) to pass along with this callback in my php class:

```
($this, 'updateDuplicateAcronym')
```

The method updateDuplicateAcronym should recieve 2 parameters, one by reference from the form where this code belongs (which works fine), and one more that I need in order to do some checks.

Someone who knows how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the hard part of this is, `updateDuplicateAcronym` is your function declaration, so it is based on the arguments that function expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my method to pass parameters :

```
$callBackFunction = function($p1, $p2) {
    ...
}

baseFunction($context, $callable, $params) 
{
    //Main process

    call_user_func($callable, $params);
}

// Running
baseFunction($this, $callBackFunction, array(1, 42));
```